# open-vm-tools drag & drop doesn't work

Tags: 22.04, vmware, drag-and-drop

## UPDATE

I found that doing a copy-paste from the host machine to the VM gives an "Error while copying", but, doing "skip all" the file is still copied

---

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04  on a 64-bit Intel Mac with VMware Fusion Player 13.5.1.

VM installation gave no problems, it works regularly and is up to date.

On the other hand, the tools that handle copy/paste and drag & drop from the host machine to the Ubuntu virtual machine are not good at all.

Any file I try to drag to the Ubuntu desktop gives me error "an invalid drag type was used".

I don't know if it is a problem with the settings or the version of the open-vm-tools (version 2:12.3.5-3~ubuntu 22.04.1 is installed).

Comment: thanks you for spelling and text correction, @Karel